# Problems mapping a typed object | Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature

Tags: typescript, dictionary

I have an object called "containers" that is going to always going contain on every key the same kind of component.

The following code works as expected

```
interface Dictionary<T> {
    [key: string]: T;
}

interface GameContainer {
    zIndex: number;
}

interface Game {
    containers: Dictionary<GameContainer>;
}

const game: Game = {
    containers: {
        a: { zIndex: 2 },
        b: { zIndex: 4 }
    }
}
```

The problem arrives when trying to map "containers"

```
const something = game.containers.map(container => {
    console.log(container)
})
```

After trying this I get the error

> Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type 'GameContainer' has no compatible call signatures.

Which is strange for me because in normal javascript this just works.

[Here is a link to a typescript playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20Dictionary%3CT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3A%20T%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20GameContainer%20%7B%0D%0A%09zIndex%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20Game%20%7B%0D%0A%09containers%3A%20Dictionary%3CGameContainer%3E%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20game%3A%20Game%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20containers%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20a%3A%20%7B%20zIndex%3A%202%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20b%3A%20%7B%20zIndex%3A%204%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20something%20%3D%20game.containers.map(container%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(container)%0D%0A%7D)) so you can see the error

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
declare module namespace {

    export interface A {
        zIndex: number;
    }

    export interface B {
        zIndex: number;
    }

    export interface Containers {
        a: A;
        b: B;
    }

    export interface RootObject {
        containers: Containers;
    }

}
```

**Using:**

```
const game: RootObject = {
    containers: {
        a: { zIndex: 2 },
        b: { zIndex: 4 }
    }
}
```

Then iterate this:

```
Object.keys(game.containers).map(function(key, index) {
   console.log(game.containers[key]);
})
```

Comment: With your example I get the error
> Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Containers'.

Also containers can have an infinite number of objects, like, c, d or whatever

Comment: Try this: `Object.keys(game.containers).map(function(key, index) {
   console.log(game.containers[key]);
})`

Comment: This works but... there is no other way to avoid Object.keys() ?

Comment: There is, you can replace `Containers` to array instead object

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172322/discussion-between-ellipticaldoor-and-opv).